# Why does the same command work differently in Makefile than it does when ran manually?

Tags: c, makefile

here's my problem : for an assignement, I'm supposed to have a Makefile that compiles a program. Easy enough. However, it doesn't work.

Here's the Makefile :

```
SRCS            =       gnl/get_next_line.c \
            $(wildcard parsing/*.c) \
            $(wildcard libft/*.c) \
            $(wildcard *.c) \

OBJS            =   ${SRCS:.c=.o}

FLAGS       =   -Wall -Wextra -Werror

NAME        =   cub3d

LIBS        =   -lX11 -lXext -std=gnu99 mlx/libmlx.a mlx/libmlx_Linux.a -lm

RM      =   rm -rf

all     :   ${NAME}

cub3d.a     :   ${OBJS} 
            ar rcs cub3d.a ${OBJS}
            ranlib cub3d.a

$(NAME)     :   cub3d.a
            gcc -o ${NAME} ${FLAGS} cub3d.c cub3d.a -I. -g ${LIBS}
```

When I run `make`, it returns a whole list of undefined references in libmlx.a. The source of my confusion is that when I just run

```
make cub3d.a && gcc -o cub3d -Wall -Wextra -Werror cub3d.c cub3d.a -I. -g -lX11 -lXext -std=gnu99 mlx/libmlx.a mlx/libmlx_Linux.a -lm
```

it works no problem.

To me it seems that the same exact line of command runs differently when executed through a Makefile than when ran manually. Why is that ? What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT : this is the command line run by the Makefile : `gcc -o cub3d -Wall -Wextra -Werror cub3d.c cub3d.a -I. -g -lX11 -lXext -std=gnu99 mlx/libmlx.a mlx/libmlx_Linux.a -lm`

Comment: Can you add the output from `make` to the question?

Comment: Not relevant to the problem, but `-std=gnu99` does not belong in LIBS

Comment: The order of the objects and libraries on the link command line is significant.  Less so for shared libraries on some systems, but definitely the relative order of `.o` and `.a` files matters.  The external dependencies of any of those are resolved only against the objects named *after* it on the command line.  I think use of wildcards in makefiles is a bad idea in general, but it is an especially bad idea if it leaves the link order underspecified.

Comment: By default, `make` shows the commands it is executing. Copy and paste the **exact** `gcc` command it is executing into the question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I added the gcc command line ran by the Makefile to the question. It seems to be the exact same.

Comment: The information in the question is not reported correctly. The makefile contents are shown as using `${FLAGS}` in the `gcc` command, and `FLAGS` is set to `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -g`, but the command line shown has `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` in one place and `-g` in another. And `LIBS` is set to `-lm -lX11…`, but the command line shown has `-lm` at the end, not before `-lX11`. Additionally, both the command line as shown and as we would expect it to expand based on the variable settings differ from the command line shown as executed manually, where the question says “when I just run…”

Comment: To diagnose problems like this, it is crucial to be correct. Some of these differences may arise from edits that have been made in the makefile at various times, resulting in different commands at different times. But to present the problem to an audience so they can reproduce it, you have to provide a set of consistent data. Further, to test the hypothesis that “the same command work[s] differently in Makefile than it does when run manually” you must at least copy and paste the **exact** command that make executes, with **no** variations in argument order.

Comment: That includes not using wildcards where make does not use wild cards. A manually typed command containing “mlx/*.a” where the make command does not contain “*” is different. I do not particularly expect differences in the order in which file names are replaced for the wildcard between the shell version and the make version, but it is one possibility that ought to be eliminated.

Comment: Due to these deviations and missing or incorrect information, I have to vote to close as missing debugging information.

Comment: My dude I've been working on it to debug it as well, no wonder there's been changes. No need to be pedantic and vote to close it, I'm just gonna make another one with the things updated, you can tell me to edit the post so that everything is up to date. I didn't think putting -lm at the end rather than in the middle would change much. I just did it 'cause someone told me it might help (it didn't). Give me two seconds and I'll put everything in order, all is fine.

Comment: There, it's all edited nice and proper, sorry for the inconvience.

Answer (score 2):

Wildcarding in the shell is [may be] different from `wildcard` in `make`.

The shell will *sort* them but `make` may *not* [probably true because the makefile isn't working whereas the shell version is].

To see if that's the case do the following in *both* the shell and the makefile:

```
echo mlx/*.a
```

You probably have a symbol that is defined in (e.g.) `y.a` and referenced in `x.a` but the wildcard [in the makefile] produces the order: `y.a x.a`

The shell wildcard would produce the [sorted] order: `x.a y.a`, so the symbol would get resolved.

That's because the linker only scans the `*.a` in the order given it by the wildcard *once*.

So, for example, if the symbol in question was `foo`, the linker will scan `y.a` and see that `foo` is *defined* but is *not* needed/wanted [yet], so it will *not* include it.

The linker will, then, scan `x.a` and see that `foo` is wanted [a reference] and scan `x.a` and all *remaining* `whatever.a` but will *not* rescan `y.a` for it. Hence, `foo` is undefined [as far as the linker is concerned].

You may have more complex symbol interactions, so you probably want a "linker group" that forces all the `*.a` to be scanned/rescanned as a group. See `man ld`

So, you want:

```
ld ... --start-group mlx/*.a --end-group -lm ...
```

For `gcc`, this would be:

```
gcc ... -Wl,--start-group mlx/*.a -Wl,--end-group -lm ...
```

Note that I put `-lm` *after* the wildcard for *your* libraries. Although not your main issue, that will help a bit.

Comment: The makefile and the shell indeed didn't put the mlx/*.a files in the same order, but even with the order corrected, the error stayed the same.

I tried doing the W1 thing, but it returned this error : 
```gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-W1,’; did you mean ‘-Wa,’?
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--start-group’; did you mean ‘--stdarg-opt’?
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-W1,’; did you mean ‘-Wa,’?
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--eng-group’; did you mean ‘--no-out’?
```

Comment: It's _not_ `-W1` [as in "one"]. It _is_ `-Wl` [as in "linker"]. And, the option is `--end-group`. This reminds me of the old(er) typewriters. They actually did _not_ have a key for `1`, but only `l`. So, you had to use the letter when you wanted the number (e.g. `123` was `l23`). This worked because in the typical typeface/font, the `l` was very similar to a `1`

Comment: Oh damn ok, that's really misleading... I'll try with that then.

Comment: OK, I tried it like that. Now it returns ```gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wl’; did you mean ‘-W’?
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--start-group’; did you mean ‘--stdarg-opt’?
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--end-group’; did you mean ‘--no-out’?
```

Comment: Hmm ... You may want to look at `man gcc` and look at the `-Wl` section. You want: `-Wl,--start-group`. There is an alternate: `-Xlinker --start-group` [note that this is _two_ arguments vs. _one_ for `-Wl`]. `gcc` knows about many but not _all_ linker options. The `-Wl,-whatever` syntax is a way to tell `gcc` to strip off the `-Wl,` and pass the remainder to the linker unchanged. If you then look at `man ld`, it will explain how `--start-group` [and `--end-group`] work. But, note/double check that you have (e.g.) `-Wl,-whatever` and _not_ `-Wl -whatever`. The 2nd produces the error you got.

Comment: OK, I managed to get the -Wl thing to work (I just wrote it wrong of course, like an idiot), but it still returns the same error as originally. The command line ran by the Makefile is this one : ```gcc -o cub3d -Wall -Wextra -Werror cub3d.c cub3d.a -I. -g -lX11 -lXext -std=gnu99 -Wl,--start-group mlx/libmlx.a mlx/libmlx_Linux.a -Wl,--end-group -lm```.